# Django template inheritance is not working inside the folder file. How to do?

Tags: python, django

I am extending base.html inside the folder file.
My root file name is base.html and I want to extend base.html inside the folder file.

```
base.html(mainfile)
-credential(foldername)
--login.html(filename)
```

I am trying like this

```
{% extends '././base.html' %}

{% block login %} {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you provide the filetree from the app that contains the `base.html` and `login.html`?

Answer (score 0):

Since the base.html is in the immediate parent folder, you have to use '..'. Try like this:

```
{% extends '../base.html' %}
{% block login %} {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Django will check and find the base.html itself.
you only have to check 2 things:

- this is the only "base.html" into your project
- it is saved inside a folder named "templates" into the proper project or app folder